# AngularJS entity not refreshed from DTO

Tags: angularjs, jhipster, fusioncharts

I'm using JHispter, angularJS and xt fusion chart for an home data chart application

The behavior I want to implement is pretty basic : reloading data according to a change in an option list in a page already displayed

So I have put a method in the detail controller , wich is calling a method from the service
This method calls a REST resource 
which itself maps the data from the entity

The data I want to refresh is not from the database, it's computed.

Regarding the logs, the data are really computed, but it's not affecting the scope.
I tend to believe that the data is computed after , or the object is not returned

I'm beginner in AngularJS and I have made a lot of redoing in those code parts, so please excuse the dirty code and the fact that i'm surely not making this right

Controller :

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('dashboardsApp')
    .controller('ChartDetailController', ChartDetailController);

ChartDetailController.$inject = ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$stateParams', 'entity', 'Chart', 'Client', 'Device', 'Selecteur', 'ChartParam', 'TypeChart'];

function ChartDetailController($scope, $rootScope, $stateParams, entity, Chart, Client, Device, Selecteur, ChartParam, TypeChart) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.chart = entity;
    console.log ("!!!   entity.id : " + entity.id);
    vm.devices = Chart.getDevices({id : entity.id});
    $scope.periodicites = {
       "Heure" : "HEURE" ,
       "Jour" : "JOURNEE" ,
       "Semaine" : "SEMAINE" ,
       "Mois" : "MOIS" ,
       "Année" : "ANNEE" ,
       "Temps réel" : "TEMPSREEL" 
};

$scope.changePeriodicite = function () {
    entity = Chart.refresh({id : entity.id, pitch: $scope.periodicite});

    entity = $scope.vm.chart ;
    console.log("dataset : " + entity.dataset );
    console.log("id : " + entity.id );
    console.log("jsonparam : " + entity.jsonparam );
    console.log("chart:entity.attrs" + entity.attrs );
    FusionCharts.render({type: vm.chart.nameTypeChart, renderAt:"chartobject-1", chart:entity.attrs, dataSource : entity.dataset });
}

    var unsubscribe = $rootScope.$on('dashboardsApp:chartUpdate', function(event, result) {
        vm.chart = result; 
    });
    $scope.$on('$destroy', unsubscribe);


}
})();
```

Service :

```
(function() {
'use strict';
angular
    .module('dashboardsApp')
    .factory('Chart', Chart);

Chart.$inject = ['$resource'];

function Chart ($resource) {
    var resourceUrl =  'api/charts/:id/:subResource/:pitch';

    return $resource(resourceUrl, {}, {
        'query': { method: 'GET', isArray: true},
        'get': {
            method: 'GET',
            transformResponse: function (data) {
                if (data) {
                    data = angular.fromJson(data);
                }
                return data;
            }
        },
        'update': { method:'PUT' },
        'getDevices' : { method:'GET', isArray: true,  params: { subResource: 'devices'}},
        'refresh' :  { 
            method:'GET' , 
            transformResponse: function (data) {
                if (data) {
                    data = angular.fromJson(data);
                }
                return data;
            },
            params: { subResource: 'changePitch', pitch:'pitch'}} 
    });
}
})();
```

REST Resource

```
/**
 * GET  /charts/:id.changePitch : change chart Pitch and get the datas accordingly.
 *
 * @param id the id of the chartDTO to retrieve
 * @return the ResponseEntity with status 200 (OK) and with body the chartDTO, or with status 404 (Not Found)
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "/charts/{id}/changePitch/{pitch}",
    method = RequestMethod.GET,
    produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@Timed
public ResponseEntity<ChartDTO> changeChartPitch(@PathVariable Long id, @PathVariable String pitch) {
    log.debug("REST request to chnage Chart pitch : {}", id);
    Chart chart = chartRepository.findOne(id);
    ChartDTO chartDTO =  chartMapper.chartToChartDTO(chart);
    chartDTO.setCategories(pitch);
    chartDTO.setDataset(chartDTO.getDataset());
    //chartDTO =  chartMapper.chartToChartDTO(chart);
    log.info("Resource dataset :" + chartDTO.getDataset());
    log.info("Resource JSONParam :" + chartDTO.getJSONParam());

    return Optional.ofNullable(chartDTO)
        .map(result -> new ResponseEntity<>(
            result,
            HttpStatus.OK))
        .orElse(new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND));
}
```

DTO

```
    public String getDataset() {
    String returnString = "[{\"data\": []}]";
    if (this.categories != null ) {
        returnString = "[{\"data\": [";
        for (String s:this.categories) {
            returnString += "{label: \"" + s + "\", value: '" + new Random().nextInt(1000) + "'},";
        } 
        returnString += returnString.substring(0, returnString.length()-1) + "]} ] ";
        log.debug ("DTO Dataset :" + returnString);
    } else {
        log.debug ("Categories' null");
        log.debug ("DTO Dataset :" + returnString);
    }


    return returnString;
    }
```

HTML Parts

```
 <tr>
     <td>
         <table>
             <tr>
                 <td>
                     <select  ng-model="periodicite" ng-options="x for (x, y) in periodicites" ng-change="changePeriodicite()"></select>
                 </td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                 <td>
                     <md-datepicker ng-model="myDatedeb" md-placeholder="Enter date"></md-datepicker>
                 </td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                 <td>
                     <md-datepicker ng-model="myDatefin" md-placeholder="Enter date"></md-datepicker>
                 </td>
             </tr>
         </table>
     </td>
     <td>
         <div fusioncharts 
             width="600"
             height="400" 
             type="{{vm.chart.nameTypeChart}}"
             chart="{{vm.chart.jsonparam}}"
             dataset="{{vm.chart.dataset}}" >
         </div>
    </td>
 </tr>
```

logs :

```
2016-11-09 12:03:27.345 DEBUG 4110 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] c.d.d.aop.logging.LoggingAspect          : Enter: com.domoticsystem.dashboards.web.rest.ChartResource.changeChartPitch() with argument[s] = [2, HEURE]
2016-11-09 12:03:27.345 DEBUG 4110 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] c.d.dashboards.web.rest.ChartResource    : REST request to chnage Chart pitch : 2
Hibernate: select chart0_.id as id1_0_0_, chart0_.chart_id as chart_id2_0_0_, chart0_.client_id as client_i5_0_0_, chart0_.json_data_chart as json_dat3_0_0_, chart0_.nom_chart as nom_char4_0_0_, chart0_.type_chart_id as type_cha6_0_0_, client1_.id as id1_2_1_, client1_.client_adress as client_a2_2_1_, client1_.client_city as client_c3_2_1_, client1_.client_id as client_i4_2_1_, client1_.client_name as client_n5_2_1_, client1_.client_zip as client_z6_2_1_, selections2_.chart_id as chart_id6_0_2_, selections2_.id as id1_1_2_, selections2_.id as id1_1_3_, selections2_.chart_id as chart_id6_1_3_, selections2_.default_value as default_2_1_3_, selections2_.name as name3_1_3_, selections2_.type as type4_1_3_, selections2_.type_chart_id as type_cha7_1_3_, selections2_.value as value5_1_3_, typechart3_.id as id1_15_4_, typechart3_.type_name_chart as type_nam2_15_4_, typechart4_.id as id1_15_5_, typechart4_.type_name_chart as type_nam2_15_5_ from chart chart0_ left outer join client client1_ on chart0_.client_id=client1_.id left outer join chart_param selections2_ on chart0_.id=selections2_.chart_id left outer join type_chart typechart3_ on selections2_.type_chart_id=typechart3_.id left outer join type_chart typechart4_ on chart0_.type_chart_id=typechart4_.id where chart0_.id=?
2016-11-09 12:03:27.391 DEBUG 4110 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] c.d.d.aop.logging.LoggingAspect          : Enter: com.domoticsystem.dashboards.web.rest.mapper.ChartMapper.chartToChartDTO() with argument[s] = [Chart{id=2, chartId='2', nomChart='Chart numéro 2', jsonDataChart='null'}]
2016-11-09 12:03:27.391 DEBUG 4110 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] c.d.d.aop.logging.LoggingAspect          : Exit: com.domoticsystem.dashboards.web.rest.mapper.ChartMapper.chartToChartDTO() with result = ChartDTO{id=2, chartId='2', nomChart='Chart numéro 2', jsonDataChart='null'}
2016-11-09 12:03:27.406 DEBUG 4110 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] c.d.dashboards.web.rest.dto.ChartDTO     : DTO Dataset :[{"data": [{label: "0", value: '1'},{label: "10", value: '348'},{label: "20", value: '309'},{label: "30", value: '98'},{label: "40", value: '637'},{label: "50", value: '86'},[{"data": [{label: "0", value: '1'},{label: "10", value: '348'},{label: "20", value: '309'},{label: "30", value: '98'},{label: "40", value: '637'},{label: "50", value: '86'}]} ] 
2016-11-09 12:03:27.407 DEBUG 4110 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] c.d.dashboards.web.rest.dto.ChartDTO     : DTO Dataset :[{"data": [{label: "0", value: '805'},{label: "10", value: '850'},{label: "20", value: '15'},{label: "30", value: '587'},{label: "40", value: '559'},{label: "50", value: '888'},[{"data": [{label: "0", value: '805'},{label: "10", value: '850'},{label: "20", value: '15'},{label: "30", value: '587'},{label: "40", value: '559'},{label: "50", value: '888'}]} ] 
2016-11-09 12:03:27.407  INFO 4110 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] c.d.dashboards.web.rest.ChartResource    : Resource dataset :[{"data": [{label: "0", value: '805'},{label: "10", value: '850'},{label: "20", value: '15'},{label: "30", value: '587'},{label: "40", value: '559'},{label: "50", value: '888'},[{"data": [{label: "0", value: '805'},{label: "10", value: '850'},{label: "20", value: '15'},{label: "30", value: '587'},{label: "40", value: '559'},{label: "50", value: '888'}]} ] 
2016-11-09 12:03:27.407  INFO 4110 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] c.d.dashboards.web.rest.dto.ChartDTO     : DTO jsonParam :   [   {"showvalues" : "0"},{"showcanvasborder" : "0"},{"canvasborderalpha" : "0"},{"canvasbordercolor" : "CCCCCC"},{"canvasborderthickness" : "1"},{"yaxismaxvalue" : "30000"},{"captionpadding" : "30"},{"linethickness" : "3"},{"yaxisvaluespadding" : "15"},{"legendshadow" : "0"},{"legendborderalpha" : "0"},{"palettecolors" : "#f8bd19,#008ee4,#33bdda,#e44a00,#6baa01,#583e"},{"showborder" : "0"},{"subCaption" : "Batiment du Port"},{"numberPrefix" : "kWh"},{"bgcolor" : "FFFFFF"},{"showalternatehgridcolor" : "0"},{"caption" : "Consommation Eclectrique"},{"divlinecolor" : "CCCCCC"},{"showvalues" : "0"},
2016-11-09 12:03:27.407  INFO 4110 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] c.d.dashboards.web.rest.ChartResource    : Resource JSONParam :   [   {"showvalues" : "0"},{"showcanvasborder" : "0"},{"canvasborderalpha" : "0"},{"canvasbordercolor" : "CCCCCC"},{"canvasborderthickness" : "1"},{"yaxismaxvalue" : "30000"},{"captionpadding" : "30"},{"linethickness" : "3"},{"yaxisvaluespadding" : "15"},{"legendshadow" : "0"},{"legendborderalpha" : "0"},{"palettecolors" : "#f8bd19,#008ee4,#33bdda,#e44a00,#6baa01,#583e"},{"showborder" : "0"},{"subCaption" : "Batiment du Port"},{"numberPrefix" : "kWh"},{"bgcolor" : "FFFFFF"},{"showalternatehgridcolor" : "0"},{"caption" : "Consommation Eclectrique"},{"divlinecolor" : "CCCCCC"},{"showvalues" : "0"}]
2016-11-09 12:03:27.407 DEBUG 4110 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] c.d.d.aop.logging.LoggingAspect          : Exit: com.domoticsystem.dashboards.web.rest.ChartResource.changeChartPitch() with result = <200 OK,ChartDTO{id=2, chartId='2', nomChart='Chart numéro 2', jsonDataChart='null'},{}>
2016-11-09 12:03:27.409 DEBUG 4110 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] c.d.dashboards.web.rest.dto.ChartDTO     : DTO Dataset :[{"data": [{label: "0", value: '13'},{label: "10", value: '179'},{label: "20", value: '751'},{label: "30", value: '715'},{label: "40", value: '707'},{label: "50", value: '641'},[{"data": [{label: "0", value: '13'},{label: "10", value: '179'},{label: "20", value: '751'},{label: "30", value: '715'},{label: "40", value: '707'},{label: "50", value: '641'}]} ] 
2016-11-09 12:03:27.410  INFO 4110 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] c.d.dashboards.web.rest.dto.ChartDTO     : DTO jsonParam :   [   {"showvalues" : "0"},{"showcanvasborder" : "0"},{"canvasborderalpha" : "0"},{"canvasbordercolor" : "CCCCCC"},{"canvasborderthickness" : "1"},{"yaxismaxvalue" : "30000"},{"captionpadding" : "30"},{"linethickness" : "3"},{"yaxisvaluespadding" : "15"},{"legendshadow" : "0"},{"legendborderalpha" : "0"},{"palettecolors" : "#f8bd19,#008ee4,#33bdda,#e44a00,#6baa01,#583e"},{"showborder" : "0"},{"subCaption" : "Batiment du Port"},{"numberPrefix" : "kWh"},{"bgcolor" : "FFFFFF"},{"showalternatehgridcolor" : "0"},{"caption" : "Consommation Eclectrique"},{"divlinecolor" : "CCCCCC"},{"showvalues" : "0"},
2016-11-09 12:24:48.146  WARN 4110 --- [scheduler][T#1]] org.elasticsearch.monitor.jvm            : [Eros] [gc][young][8492][20] duration [1.6s], collections [1]/[2.4s], total [1.6s]/[2.9s], memory [538.8mb]->[134.4mb]/[1.2gb], all_pools {[young] [403.5mb]->[1.7mb]/[408mb]}{[survivor] [14.3mb]->[3.4mb]/[40.5mb]}{[old] [121mb]->[129.3mb]/[981.5mb]}
```

Comment: I think you can change your **refresh** call by adding success/error callback as the $resource calls are asynchronous.. Something like **Chart.refresh(..).success(function(response){ // do something with response.. }).error(function(){ .. handler in case of any server call error})**

Comment: I tried what you said and finally got this working with promises. Thanks for the hint ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `changePeriodicite` function needs to update the bound `chart` object (and render the chart) within the success callback of `Chart.refresh`:

```
$scope.changePeriodicite = function () {
    Chart.refresh({id : entity.id, pitch: $scope.periodicite}, onSuccess, onError);

    function onSuccess(result) {
        // success callback, `result` is the retrieved chart
        vm.chart = result
        FusionCharts.render({type: vm.chart.nameTypeChart, renderAt: "chartobject-1", chart: vm.chart.attrs, dataSource: vm.chart.dataset});
    }
    function onError(error) {
        // handle error here
    }
}
```

Another option, if you prefer promises:

```
$scope.changePeriodicite = function () {
    return Chart.refresh({id : entity.id, pitch: $scope.periodicite}).$promise.then(onSuccess, onError);

    function onSuccess(result) {
        // success callback, `result` is the retrieved chart
        vm.chart = result
        FusionCharts.render({type: vm.chart.nameTypeChart, renderAt: "chartobject-1", chart: vm.chart.attrs, dataSource: vm.chart.dataset});
    }
    function onError(error) {
        // handle error here
    }
}
```

Comment: Meanwhile, I tried several things, I got this working with promises.
Thanks a lot ! :)